# Strange behaviour of Array element assignment

Tags: arrays, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Today I came across some strange behaviour of Array element assignment:

```
arr = ["a","b"]
arr2 = [1,2]
arr.unshift(arr2) #= [[1, 2], "a", "b"] 
arr.push(arr2) #=> ["a", "b", [1, 2]]
```

This makes sense, however:

```
arr[0,0] = arr2 #=> [1, 2, "a", "b"]
```

I know that in `[0,0]` the first zero is `index` and second is the number of elements to be effected in that array starting from `index`.

In my thoughts it should be the same as the `unshift`, but it's not.

Can any one explain the behavior?

Comment: Why do you think `[]` should work in the same way as `unshift`? They are different methods.

Comment: @sawa you're right , that was just a thing , but can you explain [0,0] behavior . It's quite different

Comment: I believe the doc for [Array#[\]=](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D) is quite clear: "`ary[start, length] = obj`...replaces a subarray [with the elements of `obj`] from the `start` index for `length` elements". Here you might find clearer to write `arr.insert(0,arr2)`. (If you want to insert the `arr2` at the end of `arr`, you could write `arr[arr.size,0] = arr2` or `arr.insert(arr.size, *arr2)`). Note the parallel with [str\[fixnum, fixnum\] = new_str](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we [dive into the ruby source code](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/4df168074c9e80822b4326a4539600ae7dbe0adb/array.c#L1712), we'll find a function named [rb_ary_splice](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/4df168074c9e80822b4326a4539600ae7dbe0adb/array.c#L1556) called when [array assignment happens](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/4df168074c9e80822b4326a4539600ae7dbe0adb/array.c#L1717) with three arguments (i.e. index, length, and new value):

```
static VALUE
rb_ary_aset(int argc, VALUE *argv, VALUE ary)
{
    long offset, beg, len;

    if (argc == 3) {
        rb_ary_modify_check(ary);
        beg = NUM2LONG(argv[0]);
        len = NUM2LONG(argv[1]);
        rb_ary_splice(ary, beg, len, argv[2]);
        return argv[2];
    }
[...]
```

And if we follow along in `rb_ary_splice` we'll happen upon where the magic happens:

```
static void
rb_ary_splice(VALUE ary, long beg, long len, VALUE rpl)
{
    long rlen;
    long olen;

    if (len < 0) rb_raise(rb_eIndexError, "negative length (%ld)", len);
    olen = RARRAY_LEN(ary);

    [...]

        if (len != rlen) {
            RARRAY_PTR_USE(ary, ptr,
                   MEMMOVE(ptr + beg + rlen, ptr + beg + len,
                       VALUE, olen - (beg + len)));
            ARY_SET_LEN(ary, alen);
        }
        if (rlen > 0) {
            MEMMOVE(RARRAY_PTR(ary) + beg, RARRAY_CONST_PTR(rpl), VALUE, rlen);
        }
    }
    RB_GC_GUARD(rpl);
}
```

First it makes room in the array for the new elements and updates the length:

```
RARRAY_PTR_USE(ary, ptr,
    MEMMOVE(ptr + beg + rlen, ptr + beg + len,
        VALUE, olen - (beg + len)));
ARY_SET_LEN(ary, alen);
```

Then through the magic of C pointers, it inserts the new element(s):

```
MEMMOVE(RARRAY_PTR(ary) + beg, RARRAY_CONST_PTR(rpl), VALUE, rlen);
```